# How to select a set of MCMC samples with some probability?

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, probability-inequalities

I have a set of samples gathered using MCMC of random variable $X$. Let's call this set $X_s$. How to select a subset of samples $S$such that $$ Probability(X_s(S) < constant) > 0.01 $$

I want to gather a set $X_s$ of samples so that the joint probability of any sample from the complement set having value less than the constant is less than 0.01.

Comment: The question is unclear: do you aim at the 1% quantile of the target distribution or at a form of 1% quantile for the joint distribution of the Markov chain itself?

Comment: How to calculate the first one?

Comment: The empirical quantile of the MCMC sample does converge to the true quantile of the target distribution.

Comment: I dont want to calculate the constant at which its 1% quantile. I want to calculate the subset of samples Xs that are less than the constant which obey the inequality above. Does it make sense? Is that a valid question to ask?

Comment: Please provide a numerical example as I do not see the point. If my sample is $\{1,2,2,3,4,7\}$ the subset less than $3.14$ is $\{1,2,2,3\}$, so where is the difficulty?